# How to click each pagination Index using angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

- Hi,I'm trying to implement **automatically click each pagination index**
  , initial first Index only can click after remain cannot able to
  continuous page index click.

**Code:**

```
   var count =5;
    var minPage=1;
    var Next =this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".ant-pagination-item a");
    //ajaxTable
    this.interval=setInterval(()=>{
      if(minPage>4){
        minPage=1;
        //Next[1].click();
      }
      if(count<1){
        count=5;
        Next[minPage].click(); //Once Click page index, need to continue too click all index (example 1 to 10 repeatedly)
        minPage++;
      }
      count--;
      document.getElementById("displayAutoCount").innerHTML = count+"";
    },1000);
```

**Dev Tool Console:**
[image: Console]

Answer (score 0):

try using on-select-page or ngchange event

Comment: But I'm doing  without manually select pagination page index .

Comment: Yep ,need to click each pagination index , please see above image which I was posted .0: li.ant-pagination-item.ant-pagination-item-active
1: li.ant-pagination-item reference link:https://ng.ant.design/components/pagination/en#header